# How can I specify the graph scale in the System Load Indicator?

Tags: configuration, system-monitor

The vertical axis of the graphs produced by the [System Load Indicator](https://launchpad.net/indicator-multiload) appear to scale automatically to the range of the currently displayed data. This is confusing because it visually exaggerates values during times of low CPU/network usage.

How can I set a fixed maximum value so that I know how to interpret the graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can do this with System Load Indicator. I suggest you either file a feature request on Launchpad against SLI or perhaps on Ubuntu brainstorm

http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/